# Updated version of my app should be paid in iTunes app store

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itunes, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I am new in IOS Development. I had uploaded my first app in iTunes app store which is **free**. **But now i want to update the version of my app which going to be paid**. What can i do so that the updated version of my app is being paid, please help me, it doesn't give me any option to add price to my updated version app.

Thanks

Comment: You can change at any time the price set for your app, provided you sign the agreement for paid apps on itunesconnect.

Comment: How can i do that, please help me i am new in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the price of your app when you want it, just go to itunes connect > manage your application, choose your app and selecting the button in the picture[image]

but you have to know that people who have already downloaded free previous version of your app, they will not pay for the upgrade

Answer (score 0):

You can manage your app price at any time on itunesconnect.

Just go in **Manage Your Apps** then **Rights and Pricing**